# On button click append OR... in SQL Query

Tags: sql, asp.net, append, imagebutton

Is it possible to append to an SQL query based on number of clicks on a button?

Eg. For each time I click on the button **(+)** I want to add `OR [PIN]=@LogID#` Where **#** is a number increasing for everytime I press the plus **(+)** button.

I also would like do be able to decrease the same way by using the minus **(-)** button.

A new textfield should appear for every **(+)** click with the same number **#** as the appending line in the query `OR [PIN]=@LogID#` to my SQL query `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PINCode] WHERE ([PIN]=@LogID)"`. And decrease if I click on **(-)** button.

Any idea on how to do this?
I would appreciate any links or suggestions pointing me in the right direction.

I´m not looking for a finished solution here just help on were to start.
What to search for, where to read.

**Implemented the example script recieved**

*Default.aspx.vb*

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            CreateTable()
            ViewState("MyTable") = rstData
        Else
            rstData = ViewState("MyTable")
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub CreateTable()

        rstData.Columns.Add("MyPin", GetType(String))

    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click

        RepToTable()      ' save any user edits

        Dim OneRow As DataRow
        OneRow = rstData.NewRow
        OneRow("MyPin") = rstData.Rows.Count + 1   ' optional default value??
        rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow)
        Repeater1.DataSource = rstData
        Repeater1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand

    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmdMinus_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

        RepToTable()  ' save edits
        ' remove the row user clicked on
        Dim cmdDel As ImageButton = sender
        Dim rowClick As RepeaterItem = cmdDel.Parent
        rstData.Rows(rowClick.ItemIndex).Delete()
        rstData.AcceptChanges()
        Repeater1.DataSource = rstData
        Repeater1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Sub RepToTable()
        ' move values from grid back to table
        For Each rRow As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
            rstData.Rows(rRow.ItemIndex).Item("MyPin") = CType(rRow.FindControl("txtPin"), TextBox).Text
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

        RepToTable()        ' save any user edits

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("", New SqlConnection())

            Dim strWhere As String = ""
            ' grab each repater row, add a paramter - no concat of user input - no sql injection

            For i = 0 To Repeater1.Items.Count - 1
                If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= ","
                strWhere &= "@" & i
                Dim txtPIN As TextBox = Repeater1.Items(i).FindControl("txtPin")
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@" & i, SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPIN.Text
            Next

            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from PINCode WHERE PIN IN (" & strWhere & ")"
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            Dim rstResults As New DataTable
            rstResults.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstResults.Rows
                Debug.Print("Computername = " & OneRow("PIN"))
                Debug.Print("PIN = " & OneRow("PIN"))
            Next

        End Using

    End Sub

    Protected Sub PINCodeConnectionString_Selecting(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles PINCodeConnectionString.Selecting

    End Sub
End Class
```

*Default.aspx*

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="PINCode._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="float:left">
                My Pin: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPin" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("MyPin") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdMinus" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="Content/minus.jpg" Style="height:26px;width:20px"
                    OnClick="cmdMinus_Click"/>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <br />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="Content/Plus.jpg" Height="46" Width="40" style="margin-left:20px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Database" Width="133px" />

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PINCodeConnectionString" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PINCodeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PINCode]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PINCode] SET [Status] = @Status">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="PINCodeConnectionString" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to keep the state variable that count the number of click anyway, before submitting to the server side to generate the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, since you want to be able to add 1 to "N" choices?

Then that suggests a repeater solution.

So, say we have this markup:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="float:left">
                My Pin: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPin" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("MyPin") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdMinus" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="Content/minus.png" Style="height:26px;width:20px"
                    OnClick="cmdMinus_Click"/>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <br />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="Content/Add.png" Height="46" Width="40" style="margin-left:20px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Database" Width="133px" />
```

So, we have a + button, a - button (for each row),
a database search button, and of course our simple repeater.

So, the code to load this up, and say add a row, and delete a row, we get this code:

```
Dim rstData As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        CreateTable()
        ViewState("MyTable") = rstData
    Else
        rstData = ViewState("MyTable")
    End If

End Sub

Sub CreateTable()

    rstData.Columns.Add("MyPin", GetType(String))

End Sub
```

So, say we whack + a few times, and we thus have this:

[image]

So, each time we click the + key, we get a new row. We are free to type in a value.

So, our add button code is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click

    RepToTable()      ' save any user edits

    Dim OneRow As DataRow
    OneRow = rstData.NewRow
    OneRow("MyPin") = rstData.Rows.Count + 1   ' optional default value??
    rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Repeater1.DataSource = rstData
    Repeater1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And of course we need the - button, say like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdMinus_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    RepToTable()  ' save edits
    ' remove the row user clicked on
    Dim cmdDel As ImageButton = sender
    Dim rowClick As RepeaterItem = cmdDel.Parent
    rstData.Rows(rowClick.ItemIndex).Delete()
    rstData.AcceptChanges()
    Repeater1.DataSource = rstData
    Repeater1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Ok, so that gives us, "add as many as we want"

Or remove a row.

I do have that little routine that when we add or remove (or search), the user MIGHT have editing the values, so we have a routine to take the repeater rows, and send them back to the table. That little routine is this:

```
Sub RepToTable()
    ' move values from grid back to table
    For Each rRow As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
        rstData.Rows(rRow.ItemIndex).Item("MyPin") = CType(rRow.FindControl("txtPin"), TextBox).Text
    Next
End Sub
```

So, now the only "hard" part is the search routine.

We need N options.

We can NOT use sql concattion since this is USER input. If we were to generate the numbers and user could NOT edit/change, then ok, you could just concenate here.

So, we now need the "list" of choices and we STILL want strong typed parameters, nd we still want sql injection protection.

So, this will work:

```
Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    RepToTable()        ' save any user edits

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("", New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        Dim strWhere As String = ""
        ' grab each repater row, add a paramter - no concat of user input - no sql injection

        For i = 0 To Repeater1.Items.Count - 1
            If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= ","
            strWhere &= "@" & i
            Dim txtPIN As TextBox = Repeater1.Items(i).FindControl("txtPin")
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@" & i, SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPIN.Text
        Next

        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID IN (" & strWhere & ")"
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim rstResults As New DataTable
        rstResults.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstResults.Rows
            Debug.Print("Hotel name = " & OneRow("City"))
            Debug.Print("City = " & OneRow("City"))
        Next

    End Using

End Sub
```

so, not too much code. I think one could "try" just adding HTML for the add button but as the above shows? We have really un-limited flexibility, and you can add quite much plain jane markup to that repeater, and add more functionally over time - and not really have to change much code.

Comment: Whow. Thanks o alot for this. I will try this out as soon as I can and return with the result :)

Comment: Quite new to all this. Should I place all the code within Global.asax.vb or where should the code be stored?

Comment: For code just right click when in html markup, and go view code. You now jump to the code page, or so called "code behind" for that one page. So code is placed in the code module for the given page. I don't know your previous software development, and what tools you used in the past. But, when you drop that button onto the web form/page, then you can double click on the button to THEN wire up the code you want to run for that button.  So, we assume you created a new web page, and then started drag + drop controls from toolbox to the web form. Then right click and view code is were code goes.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I've finally got som time testing your code. I', having trouble understanding how to make a connectionstring working for both select and edit. You have created a custom connection "My.Settings.TEST4" how should that be formatted? Right now all I get is that "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Comment: I just went into the project, and then settings, and used the connecting string builder in the settings area of the project. It actually puts those connection string settings into web config for you. So, no, that's not custom, it is a built in feature of .net. So from VS menu, go project->MyProject properties. Now use the settings tab, and add a connecting string (you can use the connecting string wizard at that point. Create your connection, you THEN see it appear as My.Settings.MyCustomSettingAppearsHere.